# How to sync 2-way switches

Tags: switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch

Is it possible to sync state between 2-way switches?

I would like to have ON as ON from wherever location I press the switch and OFF as OFF. Having switches in different orientation for ON state creates confusion.

I tried to find a solution but couldn't find anything that works.

Comment: How does it create confusion? Is the issue that you can't see the actual light from the switch location?

Comment: @brhans: The "confusion" arises when reaching out in the dark to throw one of the switches. Actually it isn't so much confusion as inconvenience -- You push the switch up, and if your hand slides off the lever and the light stays off, you have to push the switch down. If pushing *up* always turned the light *on* and pushing *down* always turned it *off*, your muscle memory would quickly become trained and the "convenience of electricity" would become more true.

Comment: I've been background working on inventing this, but getting it small enough for a box, safe enough to use, and paperworked enough to be legal has proven to be quite a challenge. I've been using a spring to hold it "down" and bimetalic strip wrapped with a heater-sourced resistance wire to push it "up". The switch only flips small DC signals, which activates a latching relay... Code aside, it  needs wifi and a neutral, and I can't get enough oomph to "click" state changes like I want. Maybe you can figure out something better; could be a $1m idea: Grandma/EMT-friendly smart switches.

Comment: I remember a similar question a few weeks ago.  Harper's answer is almost the same as last time also.

Comment: @dandavis Nice that you are working on this, but switches that operate as OP desires already exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not really possible. Plain switches are passive devices that are *human powered* which means there is no way to telegraph the action of one switch over to the handle of the other switch.  They're as simple as this.

### The conventional answer is Smart Switches

The best bet for your goal is to change to smart switches which include a smart remote for the 2nd etc. switch. These do not use a toggle at all, and have some sort of glass control which has the possibility of indicating state.  The switches are always powered (by rearranging wire function) and they communicate digitally.

### The deluxe, traditional answer is the GE RR7 system

However, the deluxe or commercial solution to this problem has been the GE RR7 system.  Imagine if inside a box was a simple on/off switch that controlled the light, and then two magnet solenoids which would throw the switch on or off. With RR7, the human-controlled switches rest in a center position.  "Up" or "Down" is a momentary action (it springs back to center) and that sends a shot of power to the solenoids to throw the *actual* switch on or off.  Thus, all switches are "up for on, down for off".

However, the switches do not reveal the actual system state. For that you must look at the lights under control.